# Angularjs Confirmation Modal as Directive with action

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to create angularjs directive mydialog wihc triggers the modal.Once the model is open I will have title and content,okcancel and confirm .Once the user click the confirm the corresponding action i.e. save should trigger .Here the save action is in MainCtrl .How to trigger that.

HTML Directive:

```
 <my-dialog newmodal="alertModel"  ></my-dialog>
```

ConfirmationDailog.html Code :

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$hide()">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{alertModel.Title}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{alertModel.Message}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="executeDialogAction(alertModel.action)">Confirm</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the JS part :

```
  var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);



app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal',
       function ($scope,$uibModal) {
        $scope.name = 'World';
        var alertModel = {};
        alertModel.Title = "My Title";
        alertModel.Message = "The Conent";
        alertModel.action= "save";
        $scope.alertModel = alertModel;           

        $scope.save= function () {
            alert('from outside');
        }


    }]);
```

my Dialog Directive that triggers the model

```
app.directive('myDialog', [
                        function () {
                            return {
                                scope: {
                                    mymodal: '=newmodal',

                                },
      template: "<button class='btn btn-danger' ng-lick='open(mymodal)'>Open Modal</button>",
                                controller: ModalController                                    

                            };
                        }]);

        function ModalController($uibModal, $log, $scope) {
            $scope.animationsEnabled = true;   

            $scope.open = function (alertModel) {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                    templateUrl: 'ConfirmationDailog.html',
                    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
                    scope:$scope,
                        resolve: {
                    test: function () {
                        return alertModel;
                    }
            },
                    size: 'lg'                                  
                });
                modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                    console.log("Confirmed: " + selectedItem);
                    $scope.selectedItem = selectedItem;
                }, function () {
                    $log.info('modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                });
            };
        }


        function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $uibModalInstance, test) {
            console.log('in');
            $scope.alertModel = test;
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $scope.$dismiss();
            }

            $scope.executeDialogAction = function (action) {
                if (typeof $scope[action] === "function") {
                    $scope[action]();
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: `For the older AngularJS (1.x) web framework, use the angularjs tag.` Do not use angular tag for angularjs questions

Comment: $broadcast or $emit will be help full

Comment: @MMK Please add some code the can be used for my issue.And here I dont need to pass any data,Just need to call method in the parent scope